Ring structure on relative de Rham cohomology
In Bott-Tu, for a smooth map $f:S\to M$ between two manifolds, they define a complex $\Omega^*(f)=\bigoplus_{q\geq 0} \Omega^q(f)$ by $\Omega^q(f)=\Omega^q(M)\oplus \Omega^{q-1}(S)$ with differential $d(\omega,\theta)=(d\omega, f^*\omega -d\theta)$. Then $d^2=0$ and the relative de Rham cohomology groups $H^*(f)$ are defined.
Below there is an exercise asking to show that if $f,g:S\to M$ are homotopic then $H^*(f)$ and $H^*(g)$ are isomorphic "algebras".
But how is the multiplication structure on $H^*(f)$ defined? There is no mention about it in the book. Componentwise wedge product does not seem to be well-defined..

I guess that the definition is,
$$(\omega_1,\theta_1)\cdot (\omega_2,\theta_2)=(\omega_1\wedge \omega_2,\theta_1\wedge f^*(\omega_2)+f^*(\omega_1)\wedge\theta_2).$$
A simple calculation will show that the product of two cycles is also closed.

If I try to verify the Leibniz rule for $d$ with this definition, I get one instance of $f^*(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2)$ on one side and two on the other, so they don't cancel out for whatever choice of signs
